# Multilevel Navigation Bar with Html CSS

Tags: html, css

```
<ul>
<li><a>A</a></li>
<li><a>B</a></li>
<li><a>C</a></li>
<li><a>D</a>
    <ul>
        <li><a>DA</a></li>
        <li><a>DB</a></li>
        <li><a>DC</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a>DCA</a></li>
                    <li><a>DCB</a></li>
                    <li><a>DCC</a></li>
                    <li><a>DCD</a></li>
                </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a>DD</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li><a>E</a>
    <ul>
        <li><a>EA</a></li>
        <li><a>EB</a></li>
        <li><a>EC</a></li>
        <li><a>ED</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

[image: problem detail with view]

I want to make a multilevel navigation bar in html and css (also js if needed).  I want to show the submenu with respect to its parent menu not its parent(item) and submenu should be as long as its parent menu. I tried to describe the expectation in the attached image. Please someone provide the solution with fiddle link(if possible).

https://jsfiddle.net/razin/ngqe9obc/

Comment: You can use this link to achieve what you described in you post -> https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_ref_js_dropdown_multilevel_css&stacked=h .If you face any issues with it, happy to help you fix it :)

Comment: I agree with Paulie_D. You will need CSS knowledge, and I would suggest you pay special attention at the display and position properties.

Comment: Thanks for your advise @Paulie_D. Next time i recover myself. I tried it  but it was not expected. it was second type that was marked red cross on the picture. I want to make it as first type. You can see my code https://jsfiddle.net/razin/ngqe9obc/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use css selectors:

Adjacent sibling combinator
The + combinator selects adjacent siblings. This means that the second element directly follows the first, and both share the same parent.
Syntax: A + B
Example: h2 + p will match all

elements that directly follow an .
General sibling combinator
The ~ combinator selects siblings. This means that the second element follows the first (though not necessarily immediately), and both share the same parent.
Syntax: A ~ B
Example: p ~ span will match all  elements that follow a

.